# How to integrate a PACS server (DCM4CHE) with personal database

Tags: database, dcm4che

Hi i am a newbie to programming. I have 100 or so CT scans stored on a PACS (dcm4che). I am trying to link all patients to a teaching file database (simple django application) which will have teaching points on each case. Can someone direct me to a tutorial or a brief direction to what sort of programming will integrate the two? i do realise the generic nature of the question. I have 20 days to work on this so am willing to start from scratch

Thanks

Comment: is the PACS administrated by your own?

Comment: yes, its on my PC and i have full control

Comment: Which database do you use for dcm4chee (hsqldb mysql, postgres)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to bind yiur django app or project to the appropriate dcm4chee databese. Since you have all priviliges just create a new table within dcm4chee database which has a simple foreign key column named SOPinstanceUid. In this column you just store the SOPinstanceUId of your preferred images. Then of course you can additionally provide all columns you  need for your teaching problem.

You can of course also create a seperate database and bind your django app to both databases and use the SOPInstance uid also as main key to establish the relationship between dcm4chee db and teaching db.

Within your django app you can then of course manage your teaching table or db and query the filenames of the images which you have selected for teaching.The key of this relationship is the SOPInstanceUID of the dicom image.

This approach just needs some expertise in SQL, some knowledge of the preconfigured database and of course django and DICOM.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. It gives me a place to start. If you dont mind, i would like to ask you for tips when I start working on this. Cheers

Comment: Thats no problem! Good luck until than!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against anything specific as diving into dcm4che. Instead if you would like to use standard API, you should use the QIDO-RS/WADO API provided by [dcm4chee](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dcm4che/Uqaik9GgQPY).

One of the main author did also document how to install such instance [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.protocols.dicom/gunter%2420hardcore/comp.protocols.dicom/ds42SSg7nMU/K1sETUtVS98J)

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into that. Trying to install dcm4chee-3.1.1 which uses maven, maven is not running from the downloaded dcm4chee folder and gives error that there is no POM in this directory (dcm4che-3.2.1 downloaded folder). Are you able to instruct?

Comment: Hi the version 3.2.1 is a pain to install, probably because I have no JAVA background and i could not find any details. I have gone as far as using the mvn install command, but after that, there is no way to get the server up and running. The link does not provide any further help either. Btw I am running version dcm4che version 2 successfully does that have the API you suggest or is it new in version 3?